# Php shell_exec not working when no output is needed

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm trying to make a php script to run with shell_exec but doesn't seem to be working properly.

I have 3 files: index.php, write.php and file.php.

in write.php i have this:

```
$file = 'file.txt';
$contents = 'it works';
sleep(5);
file_put_contents($file, $contents);
```

this will write some contents to the file.php

In index.php i have this:

```
shell_exec('path_to_file\php.exe write.php &');
```

This works but it needs to wait for the script to finish. Now, i've tried to make this work without needing to wait for the script to finish but with no results. What i have is this:

```
shell_exec("path_to_file\php.exe write.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

this is not working; no data is written to the file.php

Can someone help please?
thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to wait for it to finish, why are you running it as a background job (using `&`)?

Comment: @Phylogenesis, I dont. This is intended to run in background without waiting for the script to finish.

Comment: It's occurred to me that you are using Windows here. Those redirects and the `&` symbol are Unix-isms and will not work as expected in Windows. To run a command in the background on Windows, prefix it with the word `start`. For example: `start path_to_file\php.exe write.php`. For more help, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/467012/command-prompt-run-scripts-in-background-equivalent-of-linuxs-bg)

Comment: You are correct. Im running wamp server on windows. I did what you said `start path_to_file\php.exe write.php` but the result is the same. it waits for the script to finish and that's not what i want. the problem is that when i add `> /dev/null` nothing happens.

Comment: `> /dev/null` is meaningless in Windows. The equivalent is `> NUL`.

Comment: Sorry, but the page keeps loading those 5 sec in `sleep(5)`. I want the process to be completely in background. the code fires `write.php` and lets it run in background. without page loading time. pelase help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147917/discussion-between-eskimopest-and-phylogenesis).